# UDF in bigquery error

Tags: google-bigquery

I am running below simple UDF and I am getting "Error: 3.3 - 14.6: Javascript TVFs are disabled.". Does anyone have a clue about this?

Query:

```
select * from 
js(
(publicdata:samples.shakespeare),
word, word_count,
"[{name: 'word', type:'string'},
  {name: 'add5', type:'integer'}]",

  "function(r, emit) {
   var new_cnt = r.word_count+5;
   emit({word: r.word, 
         add5: new_cnt});  
  }")
```

Comment: where did you find it?

Comment: Thank you for the answer Felipe. I was trying to use UDFs and then I have seen some presentations online to use Javascript. When I tried it on Bigquery UI I get this error! Is there any other way to write UDFs?

Comment: This is the right way - unfortunately not available today.. but soon!

Comment: @FelipeHoffa I guess I have the access for testing this javascript feature. Can you tell me if the below code is correct as per syntax?                                 select * from 
js(
(publicdata:samples.shakespeare),

"[{name: 'word', type:'string'},
  {name: 'word_count', type:'integer'}]",
  
"[{name: 'word', type:'string'},
  {name: 'add5', type:'integer'}]",

  "function(r, emit) {
   var new_cnt = r.word_count+5;
   emit({word: r.word, 
         add5: new_cnt});  
  }")  => I get an error saying - Error: 3.3 - 12.6: <input_field> should be an identifier

Comment: fwiw, the query in the question is correct, while the one in the previous comment is not

Comment: good news everyone, UDFs now fully enabled on BigQuery!

Comment: @FelipeHoffa a link to a documentation?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/user-defined-functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"function(r, emit) {
   var new_cnt = r.word_count+5;
   emit({word: r.word, 
         add5: new_cnt});  
  }"
```

This `function` is a new way to write Javascript inside BigQuery SQL statements. Unfortunately this feature is still in development (today being January 2015), and not widely available.

Comment: Any forward motion on this feature from Google? Seems awfully useful.

Comment: http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2015/08/breaking-sql-barrier-google-bigquery.html